# How to create Facebook App to allow OTHERS deploy my bot? Where should I start?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, bots, facebook-apps

I am building a small bot on my own server , NODE.JS based.
My plan is to release my bot and allow people to deploy it on their facebook messenger (and other platforms).
This is NOT a stand alone facebook bot , but a bot that will be deployed by OTHERS on different platforms (let's start with webpages and facebook messenger).

So, I have never built a facebook app, especially for others to use.
Any idea where to start?

The facebook developer help is very messy and seems to focus on personal app deployment rather then BKM to create apps for others to deploy , permissions and everything I need.

Any recommended links to start reading or even better - video tutorials?

Comment: *"even better - video tutorials"* - ugh, really? Also resource requests are explicitly off topic.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe - I am sure that when you had 13 points and not over 63K points, you wanted to get that kind of answers.

Comment: Actually as you can see from my profile the overwhelming majority of my rep is from answering, not asking, and my only question is not a resource request. The [help] is available at any rep level, and makes it clear what is and isn't on topic.